# Select a part of string when find a character

Tags: c#

I need to select a part of a string ,suppose i have a string like this :`Hello::Hi`,

I use this characters `::` as a separator, so i need to separate `Hello` and `Hi`.I am using C# application form .

I googled it  ,i found something like `substring` but it didn't help me.

Best regards

Comment: Look up [`string.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`string.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx) is the right method, but the syntax is a little tricky when splitting based on a *string* versus a *character*.

The overload to split on a string takes the input as an *array* of strings so it can be distinquished from the overload that takes an array of characters (since a string can be easily cast to an array of characters), and adds a parameter for `StringSplitEntries`, which you can set to `None` to use the default option (include "empty" entries):

```
string source = "Hello::Hi";
string[] splits = source.Split(new string[] {"::"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split a string into multiple parts based on a semaphore using the `Split` function:

```
var stringToSearch = "Hello::Hi";

var foundItems = stringToSearch.Split(new[] {"::"}, 
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);            

for (int i = 0; i < foundItems.Count(); i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Item #{0}: {1}", i + 1, foundItems[i]);
}

// Ouput:
// Item #1: Hello
// Item #2: Hi
```

Comment: The word **semaphore** is typically used to refer to a threading construct. Is there another use I'm unaware of?

Comment: @Michael - I've always thought of it as a 'signal'. Probably outdated, but, for example, we used to look for a 'semaphore file' that indicated a build was complete (it was the last file to be written by the build system). So in this case I think of it as a signal that it's time to split. Maybe a misuse of the term these days?